# I want to show the image in the Access column but failed to access

Tags: c#

Using C#, I want to show the image in the Access column but failed to access.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (myQuantity[i]!=null && myQuantity[i].Length>0)
    {
        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Name"] = myName[i];
        row["Quantity"] = myQuantity[i];
        row["Price"] = myPrice[i];

        c = Convert.ToInt32(myQuantity[i]);

        int price = Convert.ToInt32(myPrice[i]) * c;
        row["Amount"] = price;
        row["Action"]=  " <img src='Images/cross.png'  />";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Fahad you can try with this code

1. with Byte storage

   ```
   //Build Column
   DataColumn column = new DataColumn("MyImage"); 
   column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Byte[]"); //Type byte[] to store image bytes.
   column.AllowDBNull = true;
   column.Caption = "My Image";

   //Add Column
   yourDataTable.Columns.Add(column); 

   //Build row
   DataRow row = table.NewRow();
   row["MyImage"] = <Image byte array>;
   yourDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
   ```
2. Or with path, you can add  control in your GridView and add bind your control with the path on image.

   asp:ImageButton id="ImageButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# Container.DataItem("pictues") %>/>